# React useState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I am getting this error for the first time. I don't know why this code is wrong. I have seen a similar example in [React.js Org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong in this code?

Comment: could you share sandbox link? that will do help to figure out the issue

Answer (score 3):

Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8, but you're only using 16.3.2. Update your version and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your project react dependency from 16.3.2 to 16.8.
Here is the link [Click here to know more about react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).